# GCD dispatch concurrent queue freeze with 'Dispatch Thread Soft Limit Reached: 64' in crash log

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

My program is a server which handles incoming requests. Each valid request is wrapped in `NSOperation` and passed to a normal `NSOperationQueue`.

Each `NSOpearation` processes its request. In some cases, there is contention at a `NSDictionary` which I use `dispatch_queue` (concurrent queue), `dispatch_barrier_async`(when set value) and `dispatch_sync`(when get value) to make this `NSDictionary` thread-safe.

I test my program with 100 requests concurrently then the process freezes sometimes. I kill the process with `SIGSEGV` to see crash log.

Most of the threads stuck at `dispatch_sync` of this queue. And there is a note below

> Dispatch Thread Soft Limit Reached: 64 (too many dispatch threads
>   blocked in synchronous operations)

What does this note really mean? What is its behavior? I cannot find information about this limit. How can I fix this issue?

I can think of 2 possible ways to avoid this problem. (which I'm going to test them and will update later)

1. Use `dispatch_semaphore` to limit submitting the block to this concurrent queue.
2. Limit `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of the `NSOperationQueue`

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: This question should help explain somewhat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213845/number-of-threads-created-by-gcd

Comment: Your solutions are basically the correct ones. If you must do blocking work in concurrent queues, you need to limit the amount of parallelism you allow. libdispatch will only self-limit for cpu-bound work.

Comment: i get the same error with "setMaxConcurrentOperationCount :NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount".

Comment: @Stephane Yep, you want to set it to some fixed number that keeps you below the max worker thread count.

Answer (score 0):

> I can think of 2 possible ways to avoid this problem. (which I'm going to test them and will update later)
>
> 1. Use `dispatch_semaphore` to limit submitting the block to this concurrent queue.
> 2. Limit `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of the `NSOperationQueue`.

Yes, those are two common patterns. For the sake of future readers, the other solution to this “exhausting worker threads” problem is Objective-C's `dispatch_apply`, also known as `concurrentPerform` in Swift, which allows concurrent operations in a manner that won’t exhaust your pool of worker threads. But that’s really only applicable when launching a whole series of tasks up front (e.g. you want to parallelize a `for` loop), not the scenario you outline in your question. But, still, for the record, `dispatch_apply`/`concurrentPerform` is the third common solution for this general problem.

> I cannot find information about this limit.

This used to be covered really nicely in WWDC 2012 video [Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712), but that video is no longer available (other WWDC 2012 videos are, but not that one, curiously). But they do walk through the limited worker thread issue in WWDC 2015 video [Building Responsive and Efficient Apps with GCD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/718/?time=1900).