# iOS : how many tasks can be run concurrently by using GCD global concurrent queue

Tags: ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

By using one of the global queues of GCD we can add tasks and they get executed concurrently. Apple documentation mentions that number of concurrent tasks depends on system load and other activities. Is there any metric or benchmark data of concurrency for a give device with certain number of cores?.

I remember reading somewhere number of concurrent threads that application run are 2 times of core available?. Is that true?.

Comment: 64 threads can run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150308/workaround-on-the-threads-limit-in-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: my question, how do you count the number of already running blocks on queue, if you don't track it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731285/how-many-blocks-are-running-on-a-queue