# How many blocks are running on a queue?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Any way to check how many blocks are running on a concurrent queue?

I want to limit running blocks in a concurrent queue, and add a new block only if this number is lower i.e. 3. Any way to do it?

The reason I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150308/workaround-on-the-threads-limit-in-grand-central-dispatch), that maximum number of threads is 64. Above it app will freeze.

Comment: The `dispatch_group_leave` is to be used together with `dispatch_group_enter`, but they are to be used when not using `dispatch_group_async`. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_enter

Comment: While you may be able to accomplish that with a dispatch semaphore, it would be much easier to use NSOperation with NSOperationQueue. NSOperationQueue is a higher level API and provides a more fine control over the execution of operations.