# How to parallelize many (100+) tasks without hitting global GCD limit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

**The problem**:

When lazy-loading a list of 100+ icons in the background, I hit the GCD thread limit (64 threads), which causes my app to freeze up with a `semaphore_wait_trap` on the main thread. I want to restructure my threading code to prevent this from happening, while still loading the icons asynchronous to prevent UI blocking.

**Context**:

My app loads a screen with SVG icons on it. The amount differs on average from 10-200. The icons get drawn by using a local SVG image or a remote SVG image (if it has a custom icon), then they get post-processed to get the final image result.

Because this takes some time, and they aren't vital for the user, I want to load and post-process them in the background, so they would pop in over time. For every icon I use the following:

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    //code to be executed in the background
    SVGKImage *iconImage = [Settings getIconImage:location];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //code to be executed on the main thread when background task is finished
        if (iconImage) {
            [iconImgView setImage:iconImage.UIImage];
        }
    });
});
```

The `getIconImage` method handles the initial loading of the base SVG, which reads it synchronized with `[NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:path]` if local, and `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&errorWithNSData]` if it should load remotely. This all happens synchronous.

Then there is some post-processing of recoloring the SVG, before it gets returned and put in the `UIImageView` on the main thread.

**Question:**

Is there a way to structure my code to allow for parallelized background loading but prevent deadlock because of too many threads?

**Solution EDIT:**

```
_iconOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
_iconOperationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 8;    

// Code will be executed on the background
[_iconOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // I/O code
    SVGKImage *baseIcon = [Settings getIconBaseSVG:location];

    // CPU-only code
    SVGKImage *iconImage = [Settings getIconImage:location withBaseSVG:baseIcon];
    UIImage *svgImage = iconImage.UIImage; // Converting SVGKImage to UIImage is expensive, so don't do this on the main thread
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // Code to be executed on the main thread when background task is finished
        if (svgImage) {
            [iconImgView setImage:svgImage];
        }
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Should you really be creating a thread for every icon? I think refactoring the code so a pool of threads is cycled and the quantity can be controlled.

Comment: Check out `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=226

Comment: Good comment @user623396! Very informative and relevant video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of directly using GCD with a concurrent queue, use an `NSOperationQueue`. Set its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to something reasonable, like 4 or 8.

If you can, you should also separate I/O from pure computation. Use the width-restricted operation queue for the I/O. The pure computation you can use an unrestricted operation queue or pure GCD for.

The reason is that I/O blocks. GCD detects that the system is idle and spins up another worker thread and starts another task from the queue. That blocks in I/O, too, so it does that some more until it hits its limit. Then, the I/O starts completing and the tasks unblock. Now you have oversubscribed the system resources (i.e. CPU) because there are more tasks in flight than cores and suddenly they are actually using CPU instead of being blocked by I/O.

Pure computation tasks don't provoke this problem because GCD sees that the system is actually busy and doesn't dequeue more tasks until earlier ones have completed.

Comment: Very good answer, and addresses my thought "Why would the queue spawn so many threads anyway?"

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Working with `NSOperationQueue` and its limit works great! I also moved my I/O code to a different method as my post-processing code. However, I am having a difficult time structuring my code to use the I/O result SVG to dispatch the post-processing. Any recommendations how to properly manage this? Perhaps via a `NSNotificationCenter` notification on the main thread?

Comment: It's hard to make suggestions without seeing your code. I wouldn't expect that `NSNotificationCenter` would be needed. Perhaps you can open a new question for this.

Comment: I understand. I have added my implementation of your solution with how I divided the code in I/O and CPU specific. Though you might be right that a new question is better for this.

Comment: You can just take everything from the "CPU-only code" comment down and put it in a `dispatch_async()` to a standard concurrent queue. So, the I/O will be on the operation queue and its concurrency will be limited to 8 simultaneous operations, but the CPU tasks will just be subject to GCD's load balancing.

Answer (score 3):

You can stay with GCD by using a semaphore something like this running the whole operation in the background otherwise waiting for the semaphore will stall the UI:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t throttleSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(8);
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
for /* Loop through your images */ {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(throttleSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
        //code to be executed in the background
        SVGKImage *iconImage = [Settings getIconImage:location];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //code to be executed on the main thread when background task is finished
            if (iconImage) {
                [iconImgView setImage:iconImage.UIImage];
            }
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(throttleSemaphore);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, when using this throttle, my app immediately freezes. Are you sure this is the right way to use the semaphore?

Comment: It's tricky without access to your code ;-) However It is based on code I have in a project I'm currently working on that works great.  Essentially you create a semaphore with your limit, attempt to increment at the start of the loop and decrement afterwards.  Once the limit is reached the thread will wait before dispatching more threads.   And I've realised that is your issue...  You need to run this operation in the background.