# AWS S3 uploading not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the following to upload images to S3. Weirdly, it doesn't even enter the Block. So, no error, no success indication...it simply doesn't return anything at all. I haven't seen this happened before.

```
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *amazonUploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    amazonUploadRequest.bucket = AWS_PICTURE_BUCKET;
    amazonUploadRequest.body = fileUrl;
    amazonUploadRequest.key = key;
    amazonUploadRequest.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    [[transferManager upload:amazonUploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask * _Nonnull task) {
//Never reaches here.
        if (task.error == nil) {
            completionBlock();
        } else {
            errorBlock(task.error);
        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

Anyone seen this issue ever? I have used this in the past to upload 1 or 2 images or even 50 images in loop. I am trying right now with 100 right now and it doesn't even execute once.

Comment: have you tried [[transferManager upload:amazonUploadRequest]  continueWithExecutor:..]??

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code, give a try using continueWithExecutor!!

Comment: @nikdange_me tried it. It doesn't enter the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

So I was using `dispatch_semaphore_t` asynchronously for each upload and it turns out [GCD has a 64 thread limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150308/workaround-on-the-threads-limit-in-grand-central-dispatch) and I was hitting that with 100 + uploads. This was making all the uploads wait (DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) and hence it seemed like AWS method wasn't responding.

I fixed it by adjusting `dispatch_semaphore_t` and getting rid of my asynchronous block for individual upload. If you find yourself in this situation, hit the `pause` button and look for the number of threads running at a time.

Thanks!