# Doing thousands of operations in parallel then waiting at the end

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I want to speed up some process so I wrote a swift CLI script that process thousands of files in parallel and write the process result of each file into a single file. (The order of the files does not really matter)

So I wrote below code and it works in the Xcode unit tests (Even with a list of approx 1200 files!) However when I execute the program from the command line without Xcode and with the same list of files it never ends. It looks like it is stuck near the end.

I read that sometimes spanning too many threads will cause the program to stop because it runs out of resources but I thought  DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform will take care of that... I have no clue why this works in XCTests and does not work in the terminal.

I have tried DispatchGroup and Semaphore approach and both have the same problem...

Any help is highly appreciated.

```swift
let filePaths: [String] = Array with thousands of file paths to process

let group = DispatchGroup()
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "my.concurrent.queue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent)
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "my.serial.queue", qos: .userInitiated)

group.enter()
concurrentQueue.async {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: filePaths.count) { (fileIndex) in
        let filePath = filePaths[fileIndex]
        let result = self.processFile(path: filePath)
        group.enter()
        serialQueue.async {
            self.writeResult(result)
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    group.leave()
}
group.wait()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150308/workaround-on-the-threads-limit-in-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: Try batching your work and only work on 6 or 8 concurrent processes at a time.  In the case of working with files, those threads are likely to sit around waiting on disk I/O for a long time - be gentle with the poor I/O system it's "slow".

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. You have code that is

   ```swift
   group.enter()
   serialQueue.async {
       self.writeResult(result)
       group.leave()
   }
   ```

   That can be simplified to:

   ```swift
   serialQueue.async(group: group) {
       self.writeResult(result)
   }
   ```
2. Consider:

   ```swift
   group.enter()
   concurrentQueue.async {
       DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: filePaths.count) { (fileIndex) in
           …                       // the synchronous work you want off the main thread
       }
       group.leave()
   }
   group.wait()
   ```

   If you really are going to `wait`, that renders the `concurrentQueue` redundant. This can be simplified to:

   ```swift
   DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: filePaths.count) { (fileIndex) in
       …                           // the synchronous work you want off the main thread
   }
   ```
3. Or, if this wasn’t a CLI, we would avoid `wait`, which blocks the current queue:

   ```swift
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
       DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: filePaths.count) { (fileIndex) in
           …                       // the synchronous work you want off the main thread
       }
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           …                       // whatever you want to do when this is all done
       }
   }
   ```

But, since this is a CLI, perhaps simply:

```swift
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: filePaths.count) { fileIndex in
    let filePath = filePaths[fileIndex]
    let result = processFile(path: filePath)
    writeResult(result)
}
```