# PHImageManager's requestImage locks UI when scrolling through thousands of images

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uikit, photosframework

I have a collection view where I display all user's photos. Basic stuff, a Data Source who fetches PHAssets and use `requestImage` on  a `PHCachingImageManager` to load thumbnails.

But recently I got a bug report where the UI freezes when you have more then 5000 images and quickly scrolls through it. Upon investigating, I was able to reproduce the issue, and it seems that the main thread is locked (_lock_wait) right after calling `requestImage`, while dozens of other threads created by that call (the thumbnails for the other cells) are also locked waiting for who knows what.

I tried several things and nothing works:

1. Implemented `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching`, and used `PHCachingImageManager` to startCachingImages on the `prefetchItemsAt` event. Funny thing, it made things even worse, as it tries to load more images at once. And the `cancelPrefetchingForItemsAt`, who was supposed to be called when the cell is out of screen, is never called.
2. Tried to call `cancelImageRequest` on slower requests, also no success here.

Now I don't know what else to do, I could run `requestImage` on a background dispatch_queue so it won't lock my main thread, but it feels weird since the method will spawn another thread by itself

My code is something like that:

```
let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
requestOptions.resizeMode = .fast
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
return requestOptions

myManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 375, height: 375), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) { /* use image */ }
```

ps: I'm not sure, but it seems this only happen on iOS 11, right now I only was able to reproduce on an iPhone X

Comment: Didd you check with synchrnous mode to true

Comment: I'm testing it right now, it works better, but then I lose the option of loading a faster, lower quality image before the high quality one is done...

Comment: Oh, I still get the lock, but now in a later stage of the app when I set the current opengl context. This is really weird.

Comment: It seems that cancelImageRequest when reusing the cells did the job! But I still need to confirm with the client. I'll update the answer if this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was the issue: [GCD dispatch concurrent queue freeze with 'Dispatch Thread Soft Limit Reached: 64' in crash log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027824/gcd-dispatch-concurrent-queue-freeze-with-dispatch-thread-soft-limit-reached-6)

`requestImage` keep creating new threads until it reaches the dispatch thread limit and UI freezes on this _lock_wait

Solution was to set the `requestOptions.isSynchronous = true`, create an OperationQueue with limited concurrency and add the image fetching as jobs on that queue.

```
//somewhere like viewDidLoad
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 54

//when setting up the cells
operationQueue.addOperation { [weak self] in
      self?.cachingImageManager.requestImage(/* params...*/) { (image) in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
               //use image
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: How do you get lower-quality images on fast scrolling in this case? Also, how do you manage request cancellation?